# How can I debug Blazor WASM and javascript inside Chromium inside a browser shell winform app from within Visual Studio?

Tags: debugging, blazor, chromium, webassembly, cefsharp

I have a .net 5 C# Blazor WASM app that works in Chrome, Edge (chromium), etc.  Breakpoints in C# WASM code, javascript and webservices all fire in Visual Studio 2019. All .net code is .net core 5.

I also have a separate C# winform app (.net 4.8) that hosts CefSharp Chromium.  If I configure my above blazor solution to launch the winform app instead of a browser, then only my webservice breakpoints fire.  I have the debug port enabled in CefSharp settings in this winform app. When the winform app is running, I can access the remote debugging from another browser on port 9222.  I have access to DevTools in my Winform host and I can debug the javascript there, but I would really like to be able to debug everything, even the C# blazor code naturally inside Visual Studio as if I had launched a browser directly.

What magic is allowing Visual Studio to debug the blazor dlls inside Chrome?

Is there a way for me to have full debugging capabilities from within Visual Studio when I launch my own browser shell app instead of a native browser?

Comment: When you launch via visual studio check in task manager to see what command line args were passed to chrome/edge, might be some extra setting that needs to be enabled.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but maybe this blog from one of the aspnetcore team will at least give you more specific things to look for? https://safia.rocks/blog/blazor-wasm-debugging/

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at the command line args, the problem is launching chrome (or edge) directly, spawns 6 instances.  Two of them have a remote debugging port set to 50907 (I thought it was 9222), two other instances have a user data dir set to some visual studio temp folders.  I switched my CefSharp settings to that port but no luck.  When I start my custom chromium AppShell exe, it is only spawning 3 chromes, and only one of them has the remote port set.  Another issue is the command line args are so long that TaskManager appears to truncate and not show the entire line.